# Overlapping Axis Ticks with Margin

Tags: d3.js

My X-Axis tick number is scaling to the full width of the svg and not just the graph (without the margin area), so it overlaps.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHiIj.png The top image has margin so the labels are shown, the bottom one shows that with no margin, the ticks appear correctly

How can I make the X-axis ticks scale to the graph width instead of the svg width?

```
var margin = {top: 10, right: 0, bottom: 50, left: 0},
 width = windowWidth * 0.28 - margin.left - margin.right,
 height = 150 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale()
 .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
 .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(x)
 .orient("bottom")
 .ticks(4);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(y)
 .orient("left")
 .ticks(4);

var line = d3.svg.line()
 .interpolate("basis")
 .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
 .y(function(d) { return y(d.trials); });

var svg = d3.select("#data-graph").insert("svg")
 .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var masterLabelList = ['Total','Completed']

d3.tsv("/static/data.tsv" + '?time=' + new Date().getTime(), function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = new Date(+d.date);
  });

  var category = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, trials: +d[name]};
      })
    };
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(category, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.trials; }); }),
    d3.max(category, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.trials; }); })
    ]);

  svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "x axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
   .style("fill", "#999999")
   .call(xAxis);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. It looks to me like the x axis ticks in the two pictures are very similar. In principle, you can adjust the range of an axis through the `.range()` function of the underlying scale.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set margin's `right` property to a value greater than 0.
2. Then replace

   ```
   var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);
   ```

   with

   ```
   var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width - margin.right]);
   ```